# How high can fish get?

Tags: ridiculous-fishing

In *Ridiculous Fishing*, once the fish reach the water's surface on the way up, they fly into the air at high speeds. The background changes as they go, in that the clouds disappear, the sky gets darker, stars and the moon become visible. That's as far as I've seen, though, and I was wondering how high the fish can reach and what is the highest 'feature' (e.g. clouds, the moon, etc) visible.

There is also, as far as I can tell, no way to see the maximum height your fish have reached.

Comment: also some fish rise more than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently have a fish that is rising rapidly and at 21km.  I'm just going to let it keep going and see how high it will go.

I'm assuming this is some kind of bug because it doesn't seem to be slowing down at all, After the moon are stars, after that the stars get less and less dense and at this point there are no stars I'm just in black space.

...

I let it run over night and it was up to 800km before I shot the fish.

[image: 800km]

Comment: That's a great bug! After you posted this I did a quick search and found someone else who had the [same thing happen](http://www.giantbomb.com/forums/ridiculous-fishing-a-tale-of-redemption-236173/waaaaaaaaat-a-ridiculous-disregard-for-gravity-1429413/), so it looks like there is no upper limit:

Comment: Some fish are unaffected by gravity, particularly if they leave Earth's gravitational pull.